# RabbitMQ Listener is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I am working a asp.netcore 6.0 project

I am using RabbitMQ to cart implementation. i.e: After payment is success, Booking should be placed.

first I'm creating queue:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
                    {
                        Uri = new Uri(_config.GetValue<string>("AmpqUrl")),
                    };

                    try
                    {
                        using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
                        using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

                        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "confirmed_payments", durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                        var data = new
                        {
                            transactionId,
                            paymentConfirmedAt = DateTime.UtcNow,
                        };

                        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

                        channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "confirmed_payments", basicProperties: null, body: body);

                    }
                    catch (RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException ex)
                    {
                               Console.WriteLine("ex.ToString()");

                    }
```

and listener of it (another project):

```
 public Task ListenPaymentConfimations(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            Uri = new Uri(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AmpqUrl")),
        };

        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();

        var confimedPaymentsConsumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);

        confimedPaymentsConsumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(response,
                new { transactionId = "", paymentConfirmedAt = "" }
            );

            var date = DateTime.Parse(data.paymentConfirmedAt).ToUniversalTime();

            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            var dbService =
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITechneDbService>();

            var isPaymentConfimed = await dbService.UpdateCartPaymentConfirmedAt(data.transactionId, date);

            _logger.LogInformation("Transaction - {0}", data.transactionId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Transaction - {0}", date);
            _logger.LogInformation("Payment Confirmed - {0}", isPaymentConfimed);

            if (isPaymentConfimed)
            {
               // handle booking
            }
        };

        _channel.BasicConsume(queue: "confirmed_payments",
                     autoAck: true,
                     consumer: confimedPaymentsConsumer);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

**When I try to make hotel booking, sometimes Listener is hitted and I can made booking successfully.
But Sometimes listener in not hitted (There is no exception thrown when creating queue).**

I don't know why this happens.

Anyone can find the issue,
Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure there is only one consumer for this queue? Perhaps there are more than one and this is why you're missing some of the messages. You can look at the web management plugin to see how many consumers this queue has.

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor for your connection to indicate that consumers should be dispatched asynchronously.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
{
    Uri = new Uri(_configuration.GetValue<string>("AmpqUrl")),
    DispatchConsumersAsync = true // <---- this
};
```

You'll probably also want to change over to using `AsyncEventingBasicConsumer` instead of `EventingBasicConsumer`.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work.